# How to assign a variable to a variable using Read-Host in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables

I know the following is probably not the most efficient code in the world but its how I thought of solving the issue through my own volition.

I'd like to do the following:

```
 $1 = "Mazada"
 $2 = "Toyota"
 $3 = "Mitsubishi"

$car = Read-Host "Type Variable here" 

Write-Output = $car
```

Now the final product would give you a list of the variables in "Read-Host" command and then you would know what to type in. I know I have to solve that problem for those of you noticing the missing ingredients in the script.

Ideally I would like for anyone to type in the car choice like "$3" in the Read-Host portion and then assign it to the $car variable so that it outputs Mitsubishi.

What am I doing wrong ?

If I type in $3 i just get = $3

Thank you very much

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  What is your end-goal?

Comment: end-goal is to assign $car a car name by getting the variable from "Read-Host". So if Bob runs the script and he types $2 then $car = $2 so Write-Output = Toyota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$3` in the context of a running script is an expression that needs to be evaluated by powershell in order to return the variable's value.

When you use `Read-Host`, powerhsell will not evaluate what was entered as an expression, it just copies the characters into a string. However, it is possible to get the result you desire, using `Invoke-Expression`, but that is dangerous. You can have the user just enter the name of the variable and use the `Get-Variable` commandlet:

```
$1 = "Mazada"
$2 = "Toyota"
$3 = "Mitsubishi"

$var = Read-Host "Type Variable here name here" 

$car = get-Variable -name $var -valueonly

Write-Output "`$car=$car"
```

A better option would be to present the user with a menu of options that they choose from (e.g. 1, 2 or 3). For example (some error handling missing):

```
$cars = @("Mazada", "Toyota", "Mitsubishi")

$menuIndex = 1
Write-Host "Choose one of these cars:"
$cars | foreach {
    Write-Host $menuIndex " - $_";
    $menuIndex += 1;
 }


$ChosenItem = [int](Read-Host "Your choice (1 to $($menuIndex-1))")

$car = $cars[$ChosenItem-1]

Write-Output "`$car=$car"
```

Comment: A safer method would be `Get-Variable -Name $var.Replace('$','')`

Comment: Also, `$($_)` this syntax is unnecessary.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: You're right. Updated the answer.